# accidentally moved almost all my files in a new directory, is it the end for me?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I was working on a big Latex project and I wanted hide all the file which are not .tex, .pdf, or .png to see clearer in my directory browser.

I used the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a directory to move unwanted files
mkdir hidden_files

# Move unwanted files to the hidden_files directory
find . -type f ! -name "*.tex" ! -name "*.pdf" ! -name "*.png" -exec mv {} hidden_files/ \;
```

Where I really messed up is that instead of running it into my project directory, I did it into my root directory... It had for consequence to recursively find all the files with extension other than .tex, .pdf or .png and move them in the newly created hidden_file directory.

Is there still hope for me ? Is there a way to retrieve the original location of each of my files ?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Did you run this as root (with `sudo`) or as a regular user? Did you really run it in the `/` directory or did you mean your home? Also, minor correction, this didn't only move files with an extension other than `.pdf`, `.tex` or `.png`, it would also move any file with no extension. And it would cause any files with the same name to be overwritten which means you will also have lost some data.

Comment: you can always boot using a live usb and manually fix what you did.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. @terdon, I did not run it with sudo in the `/` directory but did it in my home directory as you suspected.
@Rinzwind, there are several thousands of files so fixing this manually seems fairly unrealistic...

Answer (score 0):

The `mv` command doesn't keep a record of file movements, and the metadata of the moved files will not contain a history of last locations.

I think your best option now will be to write some scripts to move groups of files back to their new (old) locations.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I expected that this mistake would be somehow not reversible.. 
At least, I will learn from it and be more careful in the future before executing a command..